# Is "Take Asian Pears" a complete sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

I wonder if "Take Asian pears" is a complete sentence.

I understand that for a sentence to be complete, it has to have a main clause. A main clause consists of a subject and a verb and expresses a complete thought. Someone said that the sentence is complete. I'm wavering over whether it really is complete.

Comment: It's considered a complete clause because it's an imperative: the subject of an imperative is always *you*, so that is always omitted. (But occasionally it's brought back as a "supplement": *You, take Asian pears*.)

Answer (score 1):

It is. There are at least two possible thoughts it could express.

1. "You should buy Asian pears" (as opposed to other pears, or other fruit).
2. "Start thinking about Asian pears" (in order to understand something about them). This would usually be followed by some observation about them.